# Prove that $\phi$ is tautology if only and only when $\overline{\phi}$ is tautology.

Tags: logic

Prove that $\phi$ is tautology if only and only when $\overline{\phi}$ is tautology.
**Remark**
$\phi$ must contain only $\vee$ and $\wedge$.  Forbidden are: $\tilde{}, \mathbb{false}, \mathbb{true}$.
$\overline{\phi}$ reverse conjunctions, for example $\overline{p\wedge q\vee r}=p\vee q\wedge r$.

**My approach:**
Lets use induction by number ($n$) of conjunctions.
(1) Base  $n=0$.
It is trivial because $\overline{\phi}=\phi$.
(2) Hypothesis: For each $k\le n$ where $k$ is number of conjunctions in $\phi$  we have $\phi$ is tautology if only and only when $\overline{\phi}$ is tautology.
T
(3) Induction step:
Let $\phi$ contain $n+1$ conjcutions.  Then, there are two cases:
(1) $\phi = \psi\vee p$.
(2) $\phi = \psi \wedge p$
where $\psi$ has $n$ conjcutions and fulfill induction hypothesis.
Case (1) is fairly easy - Because $\psi$  is always satisfable then $p$ may be arbitrar.
However, I have a problem with case (2).
Can you help me ? Maybe someone propose other solution ?

**Edit**  Seems to me that I managed to prove also (2).   We know that $\overline{\phi}=\overline{\psi}\vee p$, where $\overline{\psi}$ is tautology. So the same situation as (1).
Is it ok solution ?

Comment: Maybe you have to specify what is $\overline \phi$...

Comment: Look at my edition please and try to check my soltuion again, please

Comment: Without $\lnot$ (negation), $\to$, $\bot$ and $\top$ there are no tautologies.

Comment: Why (1) is "fairly easy" ? If $\phi$ is $\psi \lor p$ then $\overline \phi$ is $\overline \psi \land p$. With $p$ evaluated to *false*, if $\psi$ is taut then  $\psi \lor p$ is still *true* while  $\overline \psi \land p$ is *false*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So how to correct it ?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

Consider the case : $\phi$ is tautology (assuming that it makes sense ...) and $\phi$ is $\psi \lor p$.

Thus, $\overline \phi$ is $\overline \psi \land p$.

If $\phi$ is taut, this means that it is true for every truth assignment $v$. We have two cases :

(i) $v(\psi)=$ **t** : in this case also $v(\overline \psi)=$ **t** - by induction hypotheses - and thus $v(\overline \phi)=$ **t**.

(ii) $v(p)=$ **t**, and thus also $v(\overline \phi)=$ **t**.

---

Now for the case : $\phi$ is tautology and $\phi$ is $\psi \land p$.

If $\phi$ is taut, this means that it is true for every truth assignment $v$, and thus : $v(\psi)=v(p)=$ **t**.

From $v(\psi)=$ **t** - by induction hypotheses - we have $v(\overline \psi)=$ **t**.

Thus : $v(\overline \psi)=v(p)=$ **t** and so : $v(\overline \psi \lor p)=v(\overline \phi)=$ **t** .